# How to find a pixel's image coordinates by its rgb value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How would one find the pixels that match an RGB value in a matrix in MATLAB?

Let's suppose that I want to find the image coordinates of pixels whose value is $RGB=(144,127,11)$  for a given image in a 3d matrix format.

Is there any built-in function in MATLAB that implements this search without explicitly looping over each dimension of the matrix, thus implicitly speeding up the search by considering a vectorized approach?

Answer (score 2):

Given a RGB value as a 1d array you can get the pixel's image coordinates using a combination of the following built-in MATLAB functions [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), [prod](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) and [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
[row, col] = find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))
```

where `img` is a $N\times M\times 3$ image array and `val` is a 1d array with 3 elements $1\times 3$ or $3\times 1$, it's the RGB color value of the pixel that we want to find.

For example `reshape([144, 127, 11], 1, 1, 3)` reorganizes or reshapes the $1\times 3$ array into a $1\times 1\times 3$ 3d array to match the dimensions of the `img` array.

This is gives us the advantage of using the `==` as if we had explicitly called the following

```
im(:,:,1) == v(1)
im(:,:,2) == v(2)
im(:,:,3) == v(3)
```

Then `prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3, 3)` takes the elementwise product of each of these 2d arrays that contain truth values yielding a single 2d array that contains truth values (0 or 1), this is equivalent to calling

```
im(:,:,1) == v(1) & im(:,:,2) == v(2) & im(:,:,3) == v(3)
```

Finally, by calling `find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))` on the previous result we find the indices of all non-zero elements of the 2d array which match the RGB value.

**Note**: If you write the following `ind = find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))` instead of `[row, col] = find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))` then a linear index value will be returned instead of two indices that correspond to the pixel's coordinates in the array.

**Example**

Let's create a random image and assign the question's RGB value at indices $(3,3)$ meaning the 3 row and 3 column pixel

```
>> img = randi([0, 255], 4, 4, 3); val = [144, 127, 11]; img(3,3,:) = val
img =

ans(:,:,1) =

     2   147    61   139
   239   211    16   103
    84   184   144   238
    32   145   160    78

ans(:,:,2) =

   173    73    72   239
   122    57    39    33
   121     4   127   225
   176   160   127   186

ans(:,:,3) =

   152   110    77    38
   129    41   186    85
   102   211    11   105
    67    82   181   166
```

Now we can call reshape to see what the output looks like

```
>> reshape(val, 1, 1, 3)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =  144
ans(:,:,2) =  127
ans(:,:,3) =  11
```

the output is a $1\times 1\times 3$ array.

Next, we call the `==` operator (or `eq`):

```
>> img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =

  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0

ans(:,:,2) =

  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0
  0  0  1  0

ans(:,:,3) =

  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0
```

what this step did is to 'mark' with `1` all the elements that matched the value of their corresponding RGB channel value.

Next, we call `prod` to aggregate this 3d truth array into a 2d truth array as if we would have explicitly performed a logical `and` operation on them. The second argument given to `prod` is the dimension along we want the elementwise product to be performed. Since we want to aggregate the each color channel's 2d truth array, we will perform the product along the third dimension. This isn the resulting 2d array

```
>> prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3)
ans =

   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0
```

Finally, by calling `find`, we get the indices

```
>> [row, col] = find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))
row =  3
col =  3
```

**Note**

If we had just called `find` without the `[row, col]` assignment then the returned value would be a linear index

```
>> find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))
ans =  11
```

**Tip**

For convenience, you could also wrap the line of code into an anonymous function, should you find yourself using it multiple times, like this

```
IdxByRGB = @(img, val) find(prod(img == reshape(val, 1, 1, 3), 3))
```

and then call the function on whatever image and color value you want

```
[row, col] = IdxByRGB(img, val)
```